# backbone boilerplate code and building with grunt bbb

Tags: backbone.js, gruntjs, backbone-boilerplate

I've been following [Addy Osmani's guide on using grunt and the bbb plugin](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#backbone-boilerplate-and-grunt-bbb) to build a small backbone.js app. However, I am still confused about a couple of things. For instance, after running "bbb init" my page will not load. I get reference errors on both the css and require.js files.

I am building in a LAMP environment (MAMP on OSX). I know grunt-bbb can work off of Node.js but does it have to? Backbone after all is a client side mvc framework, so I believe it should work. When I run "bbb server" to start the development server, then everything seems fine. But I won't be able to deploy to a node server. I have to host my app on Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running your app in a subfolder? (e.g.: `localhost/my/app`) Or to the root?

Backbone-Boilerplate set the `app.root` value to `/` by default. If you're running in a subfolder, you'll need to update the value here: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/app.js#L14

Also update files path in `index.html` ([line 13](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L13) and [line 33](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L33))

If you're not using `pushState`, you can set the value to an empty string. Otherwise, add the root folder.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I updated app.root to my subdirectory and prepended that subdirectory to the paths created in index.html. I also had to change the data-main attribute in index.html to "app/config" and that worked. I guess just assumed grunt would handle the paths for you, but I guess it makes sense that grunt wouldn't know where your server root was or where you were building your project.

Comment: @user2005291 - it looks like Simon answered your question. If so the proper response on StackOverflow is to "accept" it (click the checkmark).